# How do I use a KCF tracker with an RGB and HFV mask?

Tags: python, opencv

I've been trying to change my general motion tracker into an object tracker for further implementation into a moving-camera project.

As a basic test, I've been making it track the color green using a neon green bandage.

Based off of another tutorial I saw, I cross referenced some examples to setup a color and HSV mask to differentiate green from the source frames. `cv2.imshow('mask', mask)` shows me that it is detecting the green just fine.

I want to use a KCF algorithm for a tracker, since this one seems the best one for generalized purpose and accuracy. So then I create our tracker `tracker1 = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()`. And this is where I get lost. I cannot figure out the syntax and proper way to apply my tracker onto the masks and create a box around them.

One of the many examples I was basing this off of used a read/write image method which was not in real time. Another example was using a mean-shift algorithm and implemented the mask right into the `cv2.meanshift()` method's arguments.

Upon some more googling, I found a few other examples for Python [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/object-tracking-using-opencv-cpp-python/) and [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/multitracker-multiple-object-tracking-using-opencv-c-python/). But I found it very difficult to break the code syntax down since they implemented it in a list of all the different types of algorithms. For the example video, they also seem to initialize the ROI (region of interest) at the beginning still frame for a reference point for the tracker to follow and do not use masks at all.

I also couldn't get any of the example code to run since the first line `(major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')￼` always gives me a reference error and I haven't found a way of getting it to compile otherwise. I am still relatively new to python.

Although I got the masks working, I had difficulty optimizing them to pickup the color green. I took a jpg of the color in the image and analyzed it with an online RGB color summarizer. The results can be seen in the following [image]

I then tried to use the given RGB values for the green, with a range of +(-20) on each minimum value and +(20) on every maximum value but I it could not detect the specific color. So instead, I played around with it until I got a broad enough range that worked:

```
min_green = np.array([0, 90, 0])
max_green = np.array([100, 255, 100])
```

Again, in all the examples I have been provided. They simple just "know ahead of time" the values and don't describe how to extract and interpolate the data in practice.

Here is my program stands right now.

```
from __future__ import division
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import cos, sin


# declare var first_frame.
first_frame = None

# read from webcam.
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# declare var frame_count.
frame_count = 1

# start our loop.
while True:
    # FRAME DETECTION
    # count frames.
    frame_count = frame_count + 1
    # read and store frame matrix into var 'frame'.
    check, frame = video.read()
    print(frame)

    # MOTION DETECTION
    # convert 'frame' to greyscale as 'gray'.
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # apply guassianblur on 'gray' to reduce noise.
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)

    # convert first_frame to gray for abs.dif processing later.
    if first_frame is None:
        first_frame = gray
        continue

    # COLOR DETECTION
    # apply guassianblur on frame to reduce noise.
    image_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (21, 21), 0)
    # convert to correct color scheme.
    image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image_blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    # convert to HSV.
    image_blur_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

    # COLOR FILTER
    # filter by color matrix.
    min_green = np.array([0, 90, 0])
    max_green = np.array([80, 255, 80])

    mask1 = cv2.inRange(image_blur_hsv, min_green, max_green)

    # filter by brightness.
    min_red_brightness = np.array([83, 36, 43])
    max_red_brightness = np.array([103, 56, 63])

    mask2 = cv2.inRange(image_blur_hsv, min_red_brightness, max_red_brightness)

    # take the two filters and combine.
    mask = mask1 + mask2

    cv2.imshow('mask', mask1)

    # OBJECT DETECTION
    # create a tracker.
    tracker1 = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()

    # SEGMENTATION (ALL OLDER MOTION DETECTION STUFF)
    delta_frame = cv2.absdiff(first_frame, gray)

    thresh_delta = cv2.threshold(delta_frame, 40, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    (_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh_delta.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for contour in cnts:
        if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 200:
            continue

        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow('captureFrame', frame)
    cv2.imshow('captureGrey', gray)
    cv2.imshow('delta', delta_frame)
    cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh_delta)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key == ord('q'):
        break

print(frame_count)
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: run]

Answer (score 0):

I think your threshold values for green colour are not correct. Maybe create a tracker to obtain threshold values for your specific image.

> cv.CreateTrackbar(trackbarName, windowName, value, count, onChange)> Blockquote